# If I append vectors to a dataframe within a function, is there any way to make those stay when the function is done running?

Tags: r, data-structures, dataframe

For example, here is a piece of the function:

```
dat<-read.csv(file="data.csv",sep=",",header=T) 

sigmaker<-function(x,y,z){
  dat$vuse<-voltocdf(x,y)
  dat$als<-c(voltoalph(dat$vuse,z))
  return(total(dat$vuse,dat$als))
}
sigmaker(50,20,.5)
```

Where voltocdf and voltoalph are custom functions.
And sigmaker runs fine, but when it is finished running dat does not have the vuse and als elements, even though it must have had them while the function was running for it to work.

Is there any way to make them stay as part of the dat structure after the function is finished running.

This is an abridged version of a rather large function, and I need to attach at least 7-10 rows to my dat structure.
If dat is complete at the end of the function (i.e. it has all the columns I want), is there a way I could export that as a new data structure?

Comment: Is returning the new 'dat' not an option? And please - do yourself a favor and don't get in the habit of attaching dataframes. It clutters your environment and can make debugging much more complicated.

Comment: The problem is that you are modifying the data.frame *after* calling `attach`. Your best bet is to just not use `attach` ever.

Comment: @nrussell I don't think that solves my question. I removed the attach, but the function runs fine with or without them. My problem is being able to access dat as a dataframe after the function has run.

Comment: Unless you assign the output of the modified dataframe object (built by `sigmaker`)  back to the name `dat`, the changes will not be available. Also wondering if you are really trying to re-invent the function `rbind.data.frame`. At the moment the `attach` call is completely extraneous.

Comment: Add a sample of your data with `dput(dat)`. We don't have `data.csv` on our machines. And generally speaking, it's bad practice to modify global variables from inside a function in the manner you are doing so above. If you want to operate on `dat` (or whatever object), pass it into your function as a parameter and return the modified object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is what you need, but one possible solution to your problem is passing `dat` into the function as a fourth argument and using `eval.parent(substitute(dat<-dat))` in the function body after you have applied the changes to `dat`, i.e. using

```
sigmaker<-function(x,y,z, dat){
  dat$vuse<-voltocdf(x,y)
  dat$als<-c(voltoalph(dat$vuse,z))
  eval.parent(substitute(dat<-dat))
  return(total(dat$vuse,dat$als))
}
```

The command will replace the old dat stored in the Memory location by the new one, and thereby modify it.

Let me know if this is what you need or if there is a reason why you cannot use dat as part of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The philosophy of R is that functions do not modify their arguments or the global environment (with some exceptions, but it is best to write your own functions to follow this strictly).

When you allow a function to modify the global environment (use global variables), in this case change `dat` then it leads to poor programming practice and hard to diagnose bugs.

One option (as mentioned in the comments) is to have the function return the modified `dat` and assign it yourself by calling your function like this:

```
dat <- sigmaker(x,y,z)
```

But then your function is still relying on a global variable.  What if you want to call your function on a new data frame called `dat2`.

What you are trying to do is better done using macros, or best by using object oriented programming.

Thomas Lumley wrote an article in "R News" (the predecessor to the R Journal) about writing macros in R.  It can be found in the [Sept. 2001](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/Rnews/Rnews_2001-3.pdf) issue.

Or look into the `R6` package ([here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/R6/index.html)) for one of the easier ways to do object oriented programming in R that will let you create an object and methods that will modify that object.